# inverted question mark in Latex

Tags: symbols

How do I write inverted question mark in latex.. Normally, > appears as inverted question mark but when put in an equation setting, it gives greater than.. so How do I get the inverted question mark in an equation setting.
I have tried ?` and yet it does not appear, I have also tried to put in \mbox or \text yet it is given error
>

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq8}
sr = \frac{G_{>}}{T_{runs}} \times 100
\end{equation}
```

Comment: do you mean this: ¿ ?

Comment: yes, the first one

Comment: You can just use the unicode sign if you use xelatex or lualatex, or `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` together with pdflatex.

Comment: don't set multiple letter identifiers like `runs` in math italic, use `\mathrm{runs}` or `\mathit{runs}`  for the question mark `\mbox{?\`}` should work.

Comment: Ok, if I use \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}, what code will I use for the inverted question as you can see from

Comment: `\mbox{¿}` will work in utf8 if you have specified `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` (which you have not if  `>` does not produce `>`)

Comment: I noticed you have asked 5 questions on this site, but have yet to accept one.  Did you know that you can click the up-arrow to the left of any question or answer on this site to indicate that you found value in the question or answer.  Further, when you ask a question, you can (should, when it makes sense), click on the check mark to the left of the answer that best answers your question.  It helps give other readers a sense of what might work best in a similar case for them, and it rewards the people who helped you with so-called "reputation" points.

Answer (score 19):

\text works fine for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
?`abc? $\text{?`}a=b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Don't set multiple letter identifiers like runs in math italic, use `\mathrm{runs}` or `\mathit{runs}`

For the question mark

```
\mbox{?`}
```

or

```
 \mbox{¿}
```

if you have specified

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Note that `>` only typesets as ¿ if you use the original 7-bit OT1 encoding,
if you use T1 (or any other encoding)  `>` will typeset as >.

Comment: Google leads a search of "reversed question mark latex" to this question. Could you please extend your answer for irony question marks (⸮ - [REVERSED QUESTION MARK](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2e2e/index.htm), [Irony punctuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irony_punctuation))

Comment: Or should I probably rather open a new question for that?

Answer (score 7):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_question_and_exclamation_marks#Input_methods_for_LaTeX

Here saying that you can use `\textquestiondown` or `\textexclaimdown` for the upside down `?` or `!`.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\invques}{\mathord}{operators}{`>}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00BF}{\tmquestiondown}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\tmquestiondown}{%
  \ifmmode\invques\else\textquestiondown\fi
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{¿Qué tal? $G_{¿}$}

¿Qué tal? $G_{¿}$

\end{document}
```

You can also use `_{\invques}`, of course.

[image]